# Docker desktop starting container from dangling image

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, docker-image, docker-desktop

I keep having a strange problem and I would like to know whether there is some kind of setting to change this behaviour.

I use docker desktop for Mac, and once I have generated a new image for the same project, the next attempt to start a docker container from that image will not use that new image but one of the last dangling images.

I have two solutions/workarounds to this problem but I would like to find a general solution.

**Solution/workaround 1:**
Set the version in the docker-compose.yml to "latest", and it usually works (but not even always!!) and the newest docker images is used.

Our docker-compose.yml files usually contain this piece of configuration:

```
    image: project-name
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8787:8787"
    volumes:
    - ~/containerLogs/path-to-logs
```

Only when I change image for "project-name:latest", the newest images is used, otherwise it's always a dangling image.

```
    image: project-name:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8787:8787"
    volumes:
    - ~/containerLogs/path-to-logs
```

**Solution/workaround 2:**
Remove all dangling images before starting a container for that project-name. That way only the newest image is usable.

So, my question is:
Why isn't the newest image taken automatically? I thought dangling images only use space but are actually useless - but it's not the case. They are running and preferred on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *docker-compose* with *--force-recreate*  on Mac if you do not.
docker-compose up --force-recreate --build -d